# OpenStack CLI killed

Tags: openstack

Few seconds after executing OpenStack CLI will be killed with no messages, even --help --debug was added. It was used last week without such issue.

```
# openstack --debug --help
Killed
```

What's wrong and how to investigate it?

Comment: Check logs and `dmesg`.

Comment: It's on a pod container and no major logs related to it.

Comment: Use strace to find out what happens.